# What are the possible reasons that can cause iOS to show alert for requesting location authorization?

Tags: ios, google-maps, cllocationmanager

I'm working on an old objective c project. I'm struggling with an issue. As soon as I enter to home screen OS presents a popup for "requestWhenInUseAuthorization" for location access. The home screen also has a google map.

Now the issue is that I'm not requesting permission anywhere but OS is still showing a popup for authorization. I do not want request authorization at home screen.

What I've tried so far to catch this:

1. Search the whole project for `"CLLocationManager"`, `"stopUpdatingLocation"`, `"requestWhenInUseAuthorization"` and put breakpoint and logs, but nothing is getting called.
2. setting `[self.googleMapView setMyLocationEnabled:NO];`

I want to know what are the possible reasons that can cause iOS to show alert for requesting location authorization.

Comment: What about `requestAlwaysAuthorization`? If not... maybe the project uses any kind of third party library that requests location authorization.

Comment: Yes, I searched for that too, but results are same. But the system is showing alert for WhenInUseAuthorization.

Comment: Are you using latest google maps sdk?

Comment: No, using 'GoogleMaps', '~> 2.5.0'

Comment: Is it possible for you to temporarily share the project?